# How can i block images from certain site with javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, block

I think this can be done with js..

Let's say i want to block loading images from example.com or even with a single image path?

I prefer the first variant. can i do this?

Example:

if a image is displayed in html with http://example.com/filepath, don't allow to display images from that domain or even the file path.

Comment: Block it where, for how long? Needs more detail and context.

Comment: You could I guess, itterate through the document looking for image tags, and check the source, however, a) the html will have made the call already, b) there will always be ways round it (such as redirections)

Comment: This is the sort of thing you do with browser add-ons..

Comment: i've added a example of what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. You can add JavaScript at the bottom of the page or using the `onLoad` event but at that time, the browser might have already started the requests to load the images (it can start with that as soon as it reads the image URL).

There simply is guarantee that your JavaScript executes before the highly-optimized URL loading of the browser kicks in.

You also can't load the other page in an `iframe` thanks to Same Origin Policy.

Instead, you should configure a proxy like [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) or use something like [AdBlock](http://adblockplus.org/en/).

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox you can [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) to do exactly this with all the power of Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using jquery

on body tag

```
<body onload="remove()">
```

javascript(jquery)

```
function remove()
{
    $('img').each(function() {
        if(this.src.search('somehostname') != -1)
            $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Not sure if they fired image request or not ,but they won't come in your sight for sure

Comment: Did you have to bind the event using an onload attribute? That code would run once all images had loaded. I believe you are looking for onDOMReady.